# Удаление указателя в слоте при связи destroyed()

Tags: c++, qt, память

У меня есть участок кода, который в определённых случаях генерирует ошибку, которую мне никак не удаётся понять. Связана она с освобождением памяти. В одном случае я спокойно могу удалить указатель, в другом же приложение падает. 

 
Тот самый кусок кода

```
    EditPortsWidget *editPortsTable = new EditPortsWidget;
    editPortsTable->show();
// Чистим память
    connect(editPortsTable, &EditPortsWidget::destroyed,
            [=]
    {
        delete static_cast<EditPortsWidget*>(sender() );
    });
```

Ошибка **не появляется**, если этот код вызывается при нажатии кнопки "Закрыть". Во время обработки кода, что приведён ниже, вызывается код, что располагается выше (т.к. *EditPortsWidget* посылает сигнал **distroyed()**). Вот что происходит при нажатии этой кнопки:

```
delete static_cast<EditPortsWidget*>(guiVariables.splEditPorts->widget(0) );
```

Думаю, здесь нужно объяснить. *EditPortsWidget* является наследником QWidget. При нажатии на кнопку "Закрыть" я его удаляю, получив указатель из сплиттера (он в нём размещается).

 
Ошибка **появляется**, если я закрываю программу без предварительного нажатия кнопки "Закрыть". Ни в одном из деструкторов нет удаления этого указателя, т.к. в качестве поля класса я его нигде не храню. 

Извиняюсь, если плохо объяснил. При необходимости дополню вопрос.

Comment: Вам же прилетел сигнал destroyed, объект уже удален, зачем удалять его еще раз?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Т.к. я новичок, то могу ошибаться, но в самой первой строчке была выделена память при помощи комнады *new*. После того, как виджет перестал быть нужным, мне надо освободить выделенную память, для этого я использую *delete*.

Comment: Сигнал `destroyed` прилетает сразу же перед тем, как объект будет удален, то, что вы этот сигнал получили, означает, что где-то вы этот объект как-то удаляете. Ваша конструкция не имеет смысла, вы второй раз удаляете объект по тому же адресу в памяти. Емнип, это неопределенное поведение и скорее всего и является причиной падения

Comment: А вообще надо посмотреть в дебаггер, что именно является причиной падения. Код в лямбде избыточен и его отсутствие к крашам приводить не должно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял для чего нужны такие сложности, но тем не менее предлагаю вам везде где можно заменить команду `delete <widget*>` на вызов `sender()->deleteLater()` и система сама все сделает как надо

Comment: Т.е. мне не нужно вручную освобождать память? И утечки никакой не будет?

Comment: Не нужно. Не будет.

Comment: Если дернуть `deleteLater` для уже удаленного объекта (смотрите мой комментарий к вопросу), программа скрашится с вероятностью 100%

Comment: Если для удаленного, то конечно. Но сигнал destroyed прилетает до того как объект будет удален

Comment: @BeardedBeaver абсолютно согласен, но не видя всего кода не очень понимаю зачем он здесь, поэтому вызов deleteLater это просто страховка с учетом того, что в теле лямды сендер еще живой

Comment: Да, понял, о чем вы. В этом случае краша действительно не будет, но тем не менее это избыточное действие.

Comment: Мне кажется вы не до конца понимаете как работют `QObject` в `Qt`. Если вы создаёте `QObject` и указываете ему родителя (`parent`), то при удалении родителя все его потомки (`children`) удалятся автоматически. Вот корневой `QObject` уже нужно удалять вручную, через `delete` или `QObject::deleteLater()`. `deleteLater` отработает только если имеется запущенный `eventLoop` - вызывая `deleteLater` вы откладываете операцию удаления в очередь, и эта операция выполнится когда управление вернётся к `eventLoop`

Comment: @vegorov я исходил только из его вопроса и ничего не додумывал как там у него организовано. Обратите внимание у него объект без родителя. Цикл событий работает, это понятно из текста. Можно конечно вообще не делать этого вызова deleteLater, он тут не нужен, но тогда пришлось бы объяснять где делать и когда, а так оно работает, а потом он сам поймёт что да как. А мне, все что вы написали, известно

Comment: @AlexanderChernin так я и не Вам писал. Ошибся - надо было в вопрос комментарий добавить, а не в ответ =)